# Different style of text PC and smart phone

Tags: android, css, iphone, text, styles

I have one question. I have the following design as you can see on images, but I get a different text style on different phones (iPhone 8 and Samsung Galaxy A5 2017). What is wrong here? Do you need to apply different styles for Android phones because the same problem is with Huawei phone?

[Samsung Galaxy A5 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qiT1.jpg)

[iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbBvy.jpg)

Please help,
Thanks for answers.

Guys I have found the solution. I add "max-height:99999px;" to p tag and It works fine.
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy71l.jpg)

Comment: what is wrong exactly ?

Comment: Could it be that one of Your devices is set to override app fonts and display user-defined fonts everywhere? I'd recommend search in settings for smth like that.